# Several error:500s while using tuleap

Tags: tuleap

I recently set up tuleap 8.7.99.37 on a fresh CentOS 6.7 vhdx. I followed the instructions at http://doc-en.tuleap.net/en/latest/installation-guide/full-installation.html.

I get error:500 on theses pages:

- while approving projects on admin/approve-pending.php
- on /account/
- add users to a project

What do you need to help? What steps do I have to finish to get tuleap running w/o error:500?

Comment: Are there any errors in the web server log that coincide with these 500 errors? 500 errors usually indicate bad code or a server misconfiguration.

Comment: Could you please share what pops up in `/var/log/httpd/error_log` when those 500 errors happen ?